# Inherited Methods that are not in Header File of Superclass

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, header-files

Is there a way to have "private" methods in a superclass (which are not in its header file) and still be able to access these from subclasses?

Comment: IOW, you want protected methods.

Comment: Yes. But there is none such construct in ObjC, I can just hide it from the (public) header file. So I didn't call it that way.

Comment: I know. I was just trying to clarify what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a custom category, for example:

Stuffy.h

```
// The "official" header file to be used by almost anyone

@interface Stuffy { 
    int myMember;
}

- (void) somePublicMethod;
@end
```

Stuffy+Secret.h

```
// The magic header file, which should only be used by knowledgable people

#import "Stuffy.h"

@interface Stuffy (Secret)
    - (void) _pseudoProtectedMethod;
@end
```

Stuffy.m

```
#import "Stuffy+Secret.h"

@implementation Stuffy 

- (void) somePublicMethod {
    // ...
}

@end

@implementation Stuffy (Secret)

- (void) _pseudoProtectedMethod {
    // ...
}

@end
```

Subclasses of `Stuffy` can now either import `Stuffy.h` in their `.m` files and stick to the public API, or import `Stuffy+Secret.h` and use the semi-protected stuff.

Note, that Objective-C has no true notion of `protected` or `private` methods. Basically, anyone can include `Stuffy+Secret.h` and use the stuff declared there.

Answer (score 1):

You can "cheat" several ways.  In addition to categories, you can simply cast your `Stuffy` pointer to `FunnyStuff`, and have a whole 'nother `@interface` for it.  (Just don't declare any statics and don't do an `@implementation`.)  Or, a little cleaner, cast to an `@protocol` that defines your added methods.  (And, since you're doing a subclass, you can simply add the protocol to your subclass definition, and avoid any casting.)

Keep in mind that Objective-C doesn't require that every method in an `@implementation` have a corresponding declaration in `@interface`, and method calls are entirely dynamic, effectively including name look-up.  The only thing you have to do is to trick the compiler into allowing the call.  (In fact, you can make the call with no declaration at all if you don't mind the compiler warning.)